# Missing is what in picture

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

Source:
http://gpuzzles.com/mind-teasers/pattern-series-picture-puzzle/?source=stack

What is missing in the picture?

[image]

Comment: Is Genc Kelmendi's answer correct? Is it going to be accepted?

Comment: Probably and no.

Answer (score 18):

Correct answer is [image]

The reason is not because [image] it's left of [image], because as you can see in the second row [image] it's also left of [image].

This is the order of elements: [image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

The matrix puzzle starts with the first element, then adds **each** element **once**, and also resets the pattern to repeat itself.

And this is the result:

[image]

[image] [image]

[image] [image] [image]

[image] [image][image][image]

[image] [image][image][image][image]

[image] [image][image][image][image][image]

[image] [image][image][image][image][image][image]

[image] [image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

If you line this list in 6x6 matrix, it will look like the original puzzle.

This puzzle does not use it's full enigmatic potential though. For example, it could have been much more interesting and challenging if it could have looked like this:

[image]

Comment: Even simpler: the sequence starts with a <> and the square is filled with 1, 2, 3, ... symbols from the sequence.

Comment: Diamond is 1, Right side up club is 2, etc. 1, 12, 123, 1234, etc.  Same idea, without the awkward "static dynamic reset" thingy.

Answer (score 0):

I found there are 1,2,3,4,4,6,7,8 of each suite and the number increases black,red, black, red, black, red so the second 4 should have been 5 of a black suit. The two 4's were hearts and upside down clubs. So - upside down club.

Comment: This answer is correct, but the observed pattern is a consequence of the pattern mentioned in the other answer.